# проблемы с задачей в терминале MAC OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

> Создайте файл clean и вставьте в него команду в одну строку которая
>   ищет в данном директории и поддиректории файлы которые заканчиваются
>   на "~", или начинают с "#"
>
> разрешено писать только одну строку: И без ";" '&&' и Т.Д
>
> Подсказка "man find"

Comment: ну так, почитайте ман и напишите что то виде `find . \( -name "*~" -o  -name "#*" \)  -print `, но если эти файлы нужно ещё и удалять (скрипт же называется clean), тогда где то так `find . \( -name "*~" -o  -name "#*" \)  -delete`. Это будет работать и под маком, и под линуксом. В строке нет ни ";" '&&' и, тем более  "Т.Д"

Comment: вы озаглавили вопрос словом «проблема», но не уточнили в тексте вопроса, в чём именно проблема заключается. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.